# How can I change system wide mouse sensitivity for all users?

Tags: 10.10, hardware, mouse

Using Maverick 10.10 I was using an old USB optical Microsoft wheel mouse. It died and I threw a spare on the system but it is way too fast and jerky.  I can slow it down using the command

```
xinput --set-prop "DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 5
```

and I suppose I could make a script to run at startup (for every user), but the mouse is even crazy at the login screen. Is there any way to slow it down permanently for all users and the login screen

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you edit your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.

See the manual page: `man xorg.conf`